# How to configure selendroid and test mobile application

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testing, selendroid

I was trying to implement Selendroid in my pc.
I do as follows
1.Installed JDK
2.Installed eclipse
3.Installed SDk
4.Created Environmental Variables
5.Created a Java Application in eclipse
6.Mapped  Selendroid Standalone jar,Selendroid Standalone with dependencies, Selendroid Client and Selenium Client.I used the command in console as follows 
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies -apk myapk.apk
And verified status using http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status.I created android application and was stuck after this,What do after this?

Answer (score 0):

here is  their official site link http://selendroid.io/setup.html  from where you can  complete instruction regarding your question if you face any issue  than feel free to contact

Comment: import io.selendroid.client.SelendroidDriver;
is not working